# read excel with password in python without column number

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Hi I would like to read an Excel file with Password in Python, I found the solution here:

https://davidhamann.de/2018/02/21/read-password-protected-excel-files-into-pandas-dataframe/

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

PATH = '/Users/me/Desktop/xlwings_sample.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(PATH)
sheet = wb.sheets['sample']

df = sheet['A1:C4'].options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
df
```

which works well. However the rows of data will grow, the last rows is empty. So how can I modify the Code that it can read itself without enter the number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to determine which is the last non-empty row and the last non-empty column. You could do this this way:

In my example I use a chart df from Spotify

```
import xlwings as xw

filename_read = 'C:/Users/k_sego/spotifymall.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(filename_read)
ws = wb.sheets["spotify"]
col = ws.range('A1').end('right').column
row = ws.range('A1').end('down').row
```

Here `col` and `row` are the last non empty columns and rows. Use these in your code.